# Android Market Update Comment?

Tags: android, comments, google-play

When downloading and installing updates from Android Market, you often see an update comment like

- version 1.2.14 Bugfix on...
- version 1.2.15 Added settings menu

and so on. How is that comment made? I couldn't see a update comment field in the market today.

Thanx for listening!

Comment: When I provide updates to my Market application I put the changelog in the application description at the end. AFAIK that's the only way

Comment: Thanx for the reply! I'll add a change log at the end of the description on next update. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What some devs do (which may explain the examples you've seen) is to add change descriptions to `android:versionName` in the manifest, as that can be any string.

Comment: This is just the answer I wanted! Thanx!

Comment: Be careful with this method, though.  Many users look to the description for update text, since that's where it is generally found.  If you put updates in the version name, they won't be as noticeable - plus, that text is a smaller, gray font.

Answer (score 2):

You just add the change comment at the end of your application description, optionally separated by a line of hyphens.

There's no official way of making a specific upgrade comment.